# Insert into a 2d array an element with value as an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, element

Currently, I have a 2d array, which is basiccaly like this:

```
$oriArr = array(
  [0]=>array(
     '1'=>'a',
     '2'=>'b',
     '3-1'=>'c',
     '4-1'=>'d',
     '3-2'=>'c1',
     '4-2'=>'d1' 
  ),
  [1]=>array(
     '1'=>'a',
     '2'=>'b',
     '3-1'=>'c',
     '4-1'=>'d',
     '3-2'=>'c1',
     '4-2'=>'d1', 
     '3-3'=>'c2',
     '4-3'=>'d2'
  ),
);
```

I want to split the array into 3d array by adding a new element like this:

```
$resArr= array(
      [0]=>array(
         [1]=>'a',
         [2]=>'b',
         ['items']=>array(
           [1]=>array(
              '3-'=>'c',
              '4-'=>'d',
           ),
           [2]=>array(
              '3-'=>'c1',
              '4-'=>'d1',
            )
         ),        
      ),
      [0]=>array(
         [1]=>'a',
         [2]=>'b',
         ['items']=>array(
           [1]=>array(
              '3-'=>'c',
              '4-'=>'d',
           ),
           [2]=>array(
              '3-'=>'c1',
              '4-'=>'d1',
            ),
           [3]=>array(
              '3-'=>'c2',
              '4-'=>'d2',
            )
         ),        
      ),
    );
```

I tried to split all the keys with '-' and add them to another array, but I dont know how to add a new element called 'items' and insert the values into it.

```
foreach($oriArr as $lines){            
   foreach($lines as $keys){
     $keyArr= array();                   
     if (strpos($keys, '-') !== false) {
           $keyArr[] = $keys;
     } 
   }             
}
```

Is there any way that I can split my original array? Any answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Yeah thanks I missed it. Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like below:-

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($oriArr as $key=>$oriAr){
  $items  = array();
  foreach($oriAr as $k=>$oriA){
      $exploded_key = explode('-',$k);
      if(count($exploded_key) ==2){
         $items['items'][$exploded_key[1]][$exploded_key[0].'-'] = $oriA;
      }else{
       $items[$k]=$oriA;
      }
  }
  $final_array[$key] = $items;
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/860368

Comment: Thank you a lot. It worked. I am pretty new to multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @Tedxxxx  glad to help you :):)